# How can this relation between Lucas and Fibonacci numbers be proved?

Tags: limits, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\Bigg(\dfrac{2 \cdot 10^n + 1 \cdot 10^{n-1} + 3 \cdot 10^{n-2} + 4 \cdot 10^{n-3}+...}{0\cdot 10^n + 1 \cdot 10^{n-1} + 1 \cdot 10^{n-2} + 2 \cdot 10^{n-3}+...}\Bigg) = 19
$

I noticed that the left-hand side converges to $19$, but I don’t know how to prove this identity, hence why I ask here for your help.

Comment: Just to clarify : The above coefficients are the Lucas numbers and the below coefficients the Fibonacci numbers , right ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, that’s right.

Comment: @MartinR Right, I forgot to mention that: they are finite sums with terms from $10^n$ to $10^1$, plus the next Fibonacci/Lucas number respectively.

Comment: If we denote numerator and denominator on the left fraction $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ , the equation $a(n)-19b(n)=2F_{n+1}$ seems to hold for all $n\ge 1$. This would prove that the limit is actually $19$.

Comment: The numerators satisfies the recurrence relation $$a(1)=21,a(n+1)=10a(n)+L_{n+1}$$ and the denominators $$b(1)=1,b(n+1)=10b(n)+F_{n+1}$$ Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [generating function for the Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Generating_function) is
$$
 f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n x^n = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}
$$
and the [generating function for the Lucas numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number#Generating_function) is
$$
 l(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty L_n x^n = \frac{2-x}{1-x-x^2} \, .
$$
If we divide both numerator and denominator in your fraction by $10^n$ then the numerator converges to $l(1/10)$ and the denominator converges to $f(1/10)$. It follows that the limit is
$$
 \frac{l(1/10)}{f(1/20)} = \frac{2-1/10}{1/10} = 19 \, .
$$